# How can we set external data exposed by Business Connectivity Service (BCS) in Sharepoint 2013 Online?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, bcs

I have write the code to set the external data exposed by BCS in Sharepoint 2013 using server side code. Here is the code:

```
    public void SetBusinessDataValue(object spItem,object spField, string value)
    {
        try
        {
            SPBusinessDataField businessDataField = spField as SPBusinessDataField;
            SPListItem spListItem = spItem as SPListItem;

            businessDataField.ParseAndSetValue(spListItem, value);  //Set your value here
            string fieldName = ((SPField)spField).Title;
            spListItem[businessDataField.RelatedField] = spListItem.Fields[fieldName];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.LogWriteLine("Error in method SetBusinessDataValue(). Failed to set the business data value", ex);
        }
    }
```

It works fine. However, I was not able to write the code to set the external data in SharePoint 2013 Online using SharePoint Client Object model. Can someone help to resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using sandbox solution? If yes, you can write the same server code at the sandbox solution. Please! Try it.